# how to set offset() 100px in this script?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I set the `offset()` function to do what `margin-top: 100px;` would do?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).scrollTop( $("#position_page").offset().top );  
    });
    </script>

    <div id="aboutUs">
      About us content...
    </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="position_page">
      Header content...
    </div>
```

Comment: `$(document).scrollTop( $("#position_page").offset().top - 100);` ?

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: Why not use urls with the id reference in it: `http://website.com/#position_page`? This will automatically put the view on the div you want.

Comment: Removed the `PHP` tag

Comment: bencripps you are correct.

Comment: Don't use `<br>`s for styling purposes, at least not in 2014.

Answer (score 16):

You can just add on the offset to the end of the scrollTop like this:

```
$(document).scrollTop( $("#position_page").offset().top + 100);
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtruty/rks3H/

Comment: Your jsfiddle uses `400` not `100` and the content you added is not in the right place. Also because `position_page` is the last element and does not contain any content your example always scroll all the way to the bottom. Here is an update http://jsfiddle.net/rks3H/1/

Answer (score 5):

simply add 100 to the scroll position

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#position_page").offset().top + 100);  
});
</script>

<div id="aboutUs">
  About us content...
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="position_page">
  Header content...
</div>
```

Comment: `add 100` yet `$("#position_page").offset().top - 100`